# open( ) file with (rw-r--r--)

Tags: c, permissions, system-calls

For the file-owner 00700 the system call `open ()` only allows to set mode to `S_IRWXU` (according to my man page) for the owner which is `rwx`. I want to delete the owners right to execute this newly made file via my C program.

Unfortunately, `chmod` offers no  way to change the owners rights (as far as I understood the man-page correctly) so I reckon there is a way to directly specify the desired behavior via some arguments-magic.

```
int out;
out = open(cmd->outFile, O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, /*set the rights correctly to (rw-r--r--)*/
```

Comment: If you are the owner of the file, or run your program as the owner, then the `chmod` system call should work fine. Can you please elaborate on what the problem is?

Comment: the chmod() specifies no option to set permissions regarding the owner 0700. My manpage for chmod() only offers options for changing permissions of users, groups and others

Comment: The "user" *is* the "owner" of the file. The `U` in e.g. `S_IRWXU` means "user".

Comment: so why is user (04000) and owner (0700) ?

Comment: The `04000` bit is the "set user id" flag. It sets the effective user ID of the process when executing a program to the owner of the program. It has nothing to do with read, write or execute privileges for the owner, group or other.

Comment: If you are the owner of the file, just call [`chmod`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html) with the flags `0644` for the mode.

Comment: could you specify the line of code that would to that? ? say if(open != -1){chmod(cmd->outFile, /*what do i put here?*/}

Comment: What I said: `0644`. Which is equal to `S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH`

Comment: so you do not need to DELETE existing permissions, but reset them the way they are supposed to be and every permission, that is not explicitly set is automaticially set to '-' is that right? Why dont you write an answer I will gladly accept it

Comment: The `chmod` function *sets* the exact permissions you provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the file-owner 00700 the system call `open ()` only allows to set mode to `S_IRWXU` (according to my man page) for the owner which is `rwx`.

That would be a strange man page; see [`man open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) - the description of O_CREAT points to [*<sys/stat.h>*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html), where S_IRWXU is only the first of a list of access permission bit macros.

> I want to delete the owners right to execute this newly made file via my C program.

If you specify the wanted rights right at the file creation, you need not delete one of them later.
To create the file with `rw-r--r--`, the `open` call could be:

```
out = open(cmd->outFile, O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH);
```